# MS Sql Server Trigger Before Delete

Tags: sql-server-2012

I created the following trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER SystemClearConfiguration
ON Systems
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Configurations SET ReceiverId = NULL WHERE ReceiverId = (SELECT deleted.Id from deleted);
    UPDATE Configurations SET SenderId = NULL WHERE SenderId = (SELECT deleted.Id from deleted);
END
GO
```

If I go to the database, right click on Systems and click on "edit top 200" and try to delete one line that I know I always get the error about the FK on table Configurations.

The only reason I see for this is the trigger not running before delete. On Oracle I know you can explicitly say BEFORE or AFTER, but on SQL I can't find such option.

EDIT 1 - 2016-12-07

[image: NOTE: DataTypes might not be correct]

NOTE: DataTypes might not be correct

Error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the complete error message? And maybe you could show us your table structures including the key columns as well?

Comment: Hello @Tyron78, I just added the info you requested.

Comment: Judging by the error of your trigger, I would say the reason is quite simple: NULL is not a valid ReceiverId... that's why the FK crashes. You might want to define a dummy System entry with ID -1 and Name "Unassigned" and use this instead of the NULL update.

Comment: Hello @Tyron78. For a moment I though I was really dumb for forgetting such thing as the field not being able te be null but it's not the case. :)

Comment: Oh, OK. Strange. One more thing coming to my mind is, that you should change the "where ID = " to "where ID IN" since the trigger is executed once per statement and not once per row... but I doubt that this will solve the issue at hand. I will try to simulate the situation and come back with a solution asap.

Comment: I managed to create a trigger which does as you wish. ;-) I guess the trick is to use an instead of delete trigger. Then all you have to do is add a "delete... where id in..." after the two update statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following trigger did the trick for me:

```
ALTER TRIGGER SystemClearConfiguration
ON Systems
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Configurations SET ReceiverId = NULL WHERE ReceiverId IN (SELECT deleted.Id from deleted);
    UPDATE Configurations SET SenderId = NULL WHERE SenderId IN (SELECT deleted.Id from deleted);
    DELETE Systems WHERE Id IN (SELECT deleted.Id from deleted);
END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you @Tyron78. It's a shame we can't access the old and new value like in oracle.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit different in SQL Server. But "inserted" and "deleted " do a good job most of the time.